# How to handle if the user purchased a subscription using one google play account and trying to upgrade with another google play account?

Tags: android, in-app-subscription

We have an android app that provides basic and premium monthly subscription. If a user purchases a basic monthly subscription using X google play account and after sometime if he wants to upgrade and instead of using the X account, if he upgrades it with Y google play account, How can we handle this scenario?
Because the subscription purchased using Y google play account will be considered as a new subscription not an upgrade. So we will have two subscription running parallelly. Please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, there is no way to resolve it, the account used to purchase the subscription should be the account used to update it as your subscription purchase info is linked to your Google Account.

So as far as Google and your app is concerned, new account means a new user.

If you want to implement a functionality like this you'd be better off implementing your own payment mechanism using Stripe or something else inside the app itself via your backend.

Comment: Is there any way to restrict the user to use the same google play account for upgradation? :(

Comment: @T.AnanthaBoudmanabhan It is restricted only by default? As I said it is linked to your Google Play account so if you change the account you get treated as a new user.